# Retrieve all children from a collection of parent objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, collections

I have an object called blog and an object called article.  There are many articles inside of a blog.  I select my blogs like this:

```
Dim blogs = db.Blogs.Where(Function(b) b.CompanyId = companyId)
```

How can I get all articles within the selected blogs?

I want to display the articles in a list for the selected blogs:

```
Dim articles = ' How do I get all the articles inside of the blogs found?
Return View(articles.ToList())
```

My blog entity is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Blog

    Public Property BlogId() As Integer
    Public Property CompanyId() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Description() As String
    Public Property DateCreated As Date

    Public Overridable Property Articles() As ICollection(Of Article)

    Public Overridable Property Company() As Company

End Class

Public Class BlogDbContext

    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)
    Public Property Companies As DbSet(Of Company)
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim articles = blogs.SelectMany(Function(b) b.Articles)
```